# "Error converting datatype varchar to int" when updating from Excel macro through SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, stored-procedures

I have an Excel macro for updating data in SQL Server through a stored procedure.

Stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[modkulfadquery] 
    @steuerID nvarchar(20) = null,
    @kulfirsz integer = null,
    @kulfvaros nvarchar(50) = null,
    @kulfutca nvarchar(50) = null,
    @lakcimbejdatum date = null,
    @kulfbankszlaszam nvarchar(50) = null,
    @nevID integer = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE nevlista 
    SET steuerID = @steuerID,
        kulfirsz = @kulfirsz,
        kulfvaros = @kulfvaros,
        kulfutca = @kulfutca,
        lakcimbejdatum = CONVERT(DATE, @lakcimbejdatum),
        kulfbankszlaszam = @kulfbankszlaszam
    WHERE nevID = @nevID
END
```

The macro is:

```vb
With Munka3
    elsosor = 3
    Do Until .Cells(elsosor, 1) = ""
        nevID = .Cells(elsosor, 1).Value
        steuerID = .Cells(elsosor, 3).Value
        kulfirsz = .Cells(elsosor, 4).Value
        kulfvaros = .Cells(elsosor, 5).Value
        kulfutca = .Cells(elsosor, 6).Value
        lakcimbejdatum = .Cells(elsosor, 7).Value
        kulfbankszlaszam = .Cells(elsosor, 8).Value

        Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
        cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
        cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        cmd.CommandText = "modkulfadquery"
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@nevID", adInteger, adParamInput, , nevID)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@steuerID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, steuerID)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@kulfirsz", adInteger, adParamInput, , kulfirsz)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@kulfvaros", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, kulfvaros)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@kulfutca", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, kulfutca)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@lakcimbejdatum", adDate, adParamInput, , lakcimbejdatum)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@kulfbankszlaszam", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, kulfbankszlaszam)
        cmd.Execute

        elsosor = elsosor + 1
    Loop
End With
```

Running the macro, I get the error message:

> Error converting data type varchar to int.

I checked the types of the parameters in the stored procedure, in the macro, and the Excel sheet too, and the table in SQL Server. They are all the same.

I have a similar stored procedure (does the same) for another sheet with fewer input parameters and just `nvarchar` types (except nevID), and there it works.

Comment: Which line errors out?

Comment: line cmd.execute

Comment: Try to use `adVariant`

Comment: I mean to get to know, which parameter namely errors out, you 1) make all types as `adVariant` and then 2) change types one-by-one to their original types, i.e. changed to `adVarchar` -> run proc; changed next type to `adInteger` -> run proc etc. This way you'll find out your trouble parameter.

Comment: ok, I changed the macro to advariant where it was advarchar. I gave two inputs from the excel sheet (steuerID and kulfirsz). Now the error message was: "Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to int is not allowed. Use CONVERT function to run this query"... (meanwhile I changed all the types to advariant and got the same error)

Comment: Change parameters only with adVarChar

Comment: I did that in my first try. Then came the other error message I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. For everyone who is dealing with similar problems:

The last parameter in the stored procedure was the first in the macro, so I guess the types of the input parameter were in the wrong order. I moved the @nevID parameter in the stored procedure to the first place, since then it works!

Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't believe that was my problem. Always be cautious when using Microsoft products! Please mark your answer as "correct answer" with the green check mark !

Answer (score 0):

the error is here

```
 elsosor = elsosor + 1
```

declare `elsosor` as integer, then initialize its value

Comment: elsosor is declared as integer, I just didnt copy the whole code. Its declared at the top of the module before the sub of this macro begins (dim elsosor as integer).